# Bookmarklet in Phonegap or iframe that acts as top window?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, cordova, window

I am building an app for my school in HTML and using the Github + Phonegap cloud builder to package it as .apk, .app, etc for cross platformity.

The app its self loads an external webpage. This webpage is the schools and I have permission from them to access it but I do not have access to the server its self. I wrote a bookmarklet that accomplishes the tasks I want the app to accomplish however this requires the ability to run the bookmarklet. This can be done in any standard web browser but I can't seem to figure out how to do it in Phonegap.

My first thought was to iFrame the schools's site but sadly they use every possible breakout code that even after implementing every fix I could find it still navigates the top window and not just the iFrame.

I come to you asking for help.

Is there a way to do either (or both) of the two tasks below?

- Create an iFrame that, to the page it loads, appears and functions exactly as the top window so that even when it navigates top the top window it still stays within the iFrame
- Run a javascript bookmarklet from a phonegap app without the need to involve any native code so that when this external page is loaded, additional local JS can be executed without being called by the page its self

Answer (score 0):

You can set `src` of `<content>` in config.xml file to be a remote url. (which by default points to local index.html in www directory)

`<content src="REMOTE_URL" />`

see [The config.xml file](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/config_ref_index.md.html#The%20config.xml%20File).